# Is there a function or any round about way to translate or move a geometry to specific x,y in Oracle Spatial 11g?

Tags: oracle-spatial

Is there a function or any round about way to translate/move a geometry to specific (x,y) in Oracle Spatial 11g, as that can be achieved by the `ST_Translate` function provided by PostGIS (Link: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Translate.html)?

Regards,
Shiva Shankar

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. Check out the SDO_UTIL.AFFINETRANSFORMS() function. It can perform multiple changes to a geometry: translation but also scaling, rotation, reflection and shearing.

You can combine several of those operations in a single call. The operations work in 2D or 3D.